# Postgresql Query executes to slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance

I have PostgreSql query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (reference) reference, reference_url 
FROM vehicles v 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (select reference 
     from daily_run_vehicle rv 
     WHERE ((
           handled = False 
           AND retries >= 5 ) 
           OR rv.timestamp::timestamp::date = now()::date)  
     AND v.reference=reference);
```

Where `vehicles` table has around 400k records and `daily_run_vehicle` table has around 50 million records.

Thus I need all vehicles where that vehicle is not added to `daily_run_vehicle` today or where handled column is `False` AND retries `column is >= 5`.

But the problem is that the query takes to long to execute.

Is there any way to write it better so that it executes quicker?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a "simple" explain) as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). [No screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. You can also upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com

Comment: Why the `disctinct on ()`? Without an order by this doesn't really make sense. Also: why are you casting a timestamp to a timestamp?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have more records with the same reference. And instead of `timestamp::timestamp::date` I can use `timestamp::date`?

Comment: If `timestamp` is a `timestamp` then there is no reason to cast it to a `timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory that it may be related to calling the now() function millions of times.
You could verify by running this query instead

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (reference) reference, reference_url 
FROM vehicles v 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (select reference 
     from daily_run_vehicle rv 
     WHERE ((
           handled = False 
           AND retries >= 5 ) 
           OR rv.timestamp::timestamp::date = '2019-03-06')  
     AND v.reference=reference);
```

It the performance is improved, you'll have to set today's date into a variable and use the variable in the query so making only 1 call to now.
On a side note if you use EXISTS the tradition is to have SELECT 1 FROM ... you don't care about the values just whether there's at least one or none.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I am thinking:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (v.reference) v.reference, v.reference_url 
FROM vehicles v 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                  from daily_run_vehicle rv 
                  where rv.reference = v.reference and
                        rv.handled = False and
                        rv.retries >= 5
                 ) and
      NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                  from daily_run_vehicle rv 
                  where rv.reference = v.reference and
                        rv.timestamp >= current_date::timestamp and
                        rv.timestamp >= (current_date + interval '1 day'::timestamp 
                 )
ORDER BY v.reference;
```

For this query, you want indexes on:

- `daily_run_vehicle(reference, handled, retries)`
- `daily_run_vehicle(reference, timestamp)`
- `reference_url(reference, reference_url)`